# Get supported audio format for audio recording

Tags: android

I need to record audio in my application.I had set AAC Audio encoder format to the MediaRecorder.This is supported by some devices only (depends the API level). How can I get the supported audio encoder format for audio recording before starting that.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Hi Raghav. Thanks for your response.I need to know the supported format information from the device via code, before starting the recording.

Comment: Explore ur question (say which device and what version u r using).

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct you can check the supported audio format for your device using

> android.media.AudioTrack

has the  methods to access information about audio data:

Check this,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html